# Is there a way to faciliate remembering which are alpha/beta hemiacetals of sugars?

Tags: carbohydrates

I understood the concept of hemiacetals quite well, but have considerable trouble remembering which are called $\alpha$ or $\beta$ respectively.
Is there some concept/mnemonic/common reaction/something else to faciliate remembering this convention?

Comment: The short answer is no, not really. Or, more precisely, not that I know of. Probably because $\alpha$ and $\beta$ depends on whether the sugar is a *D* or an *L*. I simply learned that for *D*, $\alpha$ means *d*own. Then everything else logically follows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you draw the Haworth projection, the alpha anomer is written with the -OH group pointing downwards (see the image), when you write the symbol alpha, you start by writing it downwards. For the beta anomer the -OH group is written upwards and when you write the symbol beta, you start writing it upwards. This mnemonic applies only to D-monosaccharides. For L-monosaccharides the opposite applies.

Actually, a better definition is that the alpha isomer has the -OH group pointing in the direction opposite to the -CH2OH group (on carbon 5), the opposite applies for the beta isomer, therefore for L-monosaccharides the -CH2OH group should point downwards and the alpha isomer will have the -OH group pointing upwards.[image]

Comment: I think, this is only true for pyranoses.

Comment: [CC what I just posted under Ringo’s post](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/53939/is-there-a-way-to-faciliate-remembering-which-are-alpha-beta-hemicatetals-of-sug/53946?noredirect=1#comment90006_53946).

Comment: I think this one is easier to remember, but make sure to read ringos post too.

Answer (score 3):

When I was studying for my organic chemistry class last semester, I ran across an [ACS published paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed067p553) that provides several useful mnemonics for interconverting Fischer and Haworth projections of monosaccharides. I believe number four is what you are looking for specifically:

> 1. Start the ring with the anomeric carbon on the right, and continue to draw the remaining atoms in the ring in a clockwise direction, ending with the ring oxygen at the top of the drawing.
> 2. Hydroxyl groups on the right (*Dextro*-) are drawn *Down*; those on the left (*Levo*-) *Levitate* up.
> 3. The last -$\ce{CH2OH}$ group is drawn be*L*ow for an L-sugar; above for a D-sugar.
> 4. The hydroxyl group attached to the anomeric carbon and the last -$\ce{CH2OH}$ group are drown *B*oth on the same side of the ring for the $\beta$-anomer; for the $\alpha$-anomer each is *A*lone.

Comment: Same comment I gave Marko. I think, this only applies to pyranoses.

Comment: @Jan the title of the article says monosaccharides. I don't see why it would only apply to hexoses.

Comment: Ah, [there’s the problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribose). It seems like it’s only strictly true for sugars that have a $\ce{CH2OH}$ as final, extracyclic group. It also doesn’t work for [galactofuranose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactose).